# ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'dateCtrl'

Tags: angular

I am getting empty date value on submit after selecting any date i can log a date. Why am i getting empty date value if i am not selecting any date and submitting using current date. Can anyone help me out yrr. Thanks in advance !!

```
     <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="dateCtrl" class="form-control-label">Date</label>
                                    <!-- <input class="form-control Pick Date" formControlName="dateCtrl" [nbDatepicker]="datepicker">
                                    <nb-datepicker #dateTimePicker formControlName="dateCtrl" (dateChange)="handleDateChange($event)"></nb-datepicker> -->
                                    <input nbInput placeholder="Pick Date" 
                                    formControlName="dateCtrl"
                                    name="dateCtrl"
                                    id="dateCtrl"
                                    [nbDatepicker]="dateTimePicker">
                                    <nb-datepicker #dateTimePicker></nb-datepicker>
                                    <br/>
                            
                                </div>
```

```
    this.createtimesheetfb = this.fb.group({
          dateCtrl: [''],
          hoursCtrl: ['', [Validators.required]],
          remarkCtrl: ['', [Validators.required]]
        });

    handleDateChange(event) {
        var date = event;
        var datePipe = new DatePipe("en-IN");
        this.setDate = datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      }
    
    
    submit(){
    console.log("Validation"this.createtimesheetfb.value);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing to add formGroup to your HTML

Comment: All set adding formgroup to html and declaring in ts.

Comment: So you're getting empty date only when you don't select anything ?

Comment: Yes, i am getting empty date if i don't select any date and take selected date

Comment: You're missing initialization for this formControl with the current Date!

Comment: @RebaiAhmed how to set formControl for current date?

Comment: 'dateCtrl': new FormControl(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -1))